# Macbook pro mid-2010 randomly cuts off. Panic report

Tags: macbook-pro

I am not sure why this keeps happening. Either plugged in or off it cuts off. If I leave a video playing on youtube it seems to be able to handle that, if that is left by itself. But if I say type into faceboook, youtube, stackexchange into the search bar fast it cuts off. It's as if I am over-exciting it or something and then it turns off. Here is the panic report that keeps appearing? any ideas?
THANKS!
[image]

Comment: Please publish a text version (not jpg) of the complete report. So far we only know your Graphics (GPU) has had a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the GPU panics are almost certainly due to a defective discrete GPU card. I have the same 2010 MBP and have noticed 10.9.3 has increased the frequency of these fatal crashes significantly.

I'm using the https://gfx.io utility to turn off this discrete card whenever possible but many apps force it on.

P.S. Here is the link from the replacement program, but it had ended: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554